# multiple insert in sql transaction avoiding duplicate keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query transaction for creating a single user.

`comapny_id + email` should be unique

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF NOT EXISTS( 
    SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = @email AND company = 'company_id'
) BEGIN

    INSERT INTO user (id, company_id, email, password) 
    VALUES   ( NEWID(), 'company_id', 'email');

    INSERT INTO user_log( id, date, type) VALUES ( 'user_id', SYSUTCDATETIME(), 'created');
    SELECT @i as 'id', 'email' as 'email';

END ELSE BEGIN
  SELECT NULL as 'id', 'email' as email;
END

END TRANSACTION


COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

How could I modify this query to support **multiple insert** so that duplicate values are discarded and only non duplicates are inserted.

I have a bulk of users around (5000-10000). I was looping through the `user object` and using the above query. But its slow, so I need to use multiple insert.

So query could be

```
 // transaction 
 INSERT INTO user(id, company_id, email, password) VALUES (),(),(),() .....

 And also return the ids of the inserted rows
```

Comment: I think it would depend on how you execute your query / how you pass on parameters. Can you give a little more details about the `big picture` ?

Comment: Define a unique constraint on `company_id, email` with `ignore_dup_key=on`. Your current code isn't thread safe anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith I will try with ignore_dup_key. could u please point me how could i make this thread safe (or maybe it should be another question).

Answer (score 3):

You can use table-valued parameters to pass multiple values as a paramter. The fist step is to create your table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfString AS TABLE (Value VARCHAR(MAX));
```

Then you can create your procedure that accepts multiple email addresses:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertUsers @Emails dbo.ListOfString READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Then to do the UPSERT only if not exists, the most thread safe way I know of is to use `MERGE` with `HOLDLOCK`:

```
MERGE [user] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS u
USING @Emails AS e
    ON e.Email = u.Email
    AND u.Company = 'company_id'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (id, company, email) 
    VALUES (NEWID(), 'company_id', e.Email)
OUTPUT inserted.id, SYSUTCDATETIME(), 'created' INTO user_log( id, date, type);
```

The output clause handles the addition of the event in the log too.

You can call this procedure using something like:

```
DECLARE @NewUser dbo.ListOfString;
INSERT @NewUser (Value)
VALUES ('Test@Test.com'), ('Test2@test.com');

EXECUTE dbo.InsertUser @NewUser;
```

I would probably be inclined to have the company as a parameter too, making your full procedure something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertUsers @Emails dbo.ListOfString READONLY, @Company VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE [user] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS u
    USING @Emails AS e
        ON e.Email = u.Email
        AND u.Company = @Company
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (id, company, email) 
        VALUES (NEWID(), @Company, e.Email)
    OUTPUT inserted.id, SYSUTCDATETIME(), 'created' INTO user_log( id, date, type);
END
```

Alternatively you could make your table valued parameter also hold the company:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.NewUser AS TABLE (Email VARCHAR(255), Company VARCHAR(100));
```

This allows adding users to two different companies at once:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertUsers @Emails dbo.NewUser READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE [user] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS u
    USING @Emails AS e
        ON e.Email = u.Email
        AND u.Company = e.Company
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (id, company, email) 
        VALUES (NEWID(), e.Company, e.Email)
    OUTPUT inserted.id, SYSUTCDATETIME(), 'created' INTO user_log( id, date, type);
END
```

Finally, as mentioned in a comment. All this work to ensure uniqueness is all well and good, but it is not a replacement for a unique constraint! This should be in place regardless of your method of insert:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[User]
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_User__Company_Email UNIQUE (Company, Email);
```